# Live jquery sql select

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello im new to jquery but i need to do a sql select and get a number from the db.
ill try and explain better i do a sql select

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `livebattle` WHERE `username` = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $values = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $values['livebattle'] ;
```

Im trying to make a live battle script. So the user sends the request and then livebattle= 0 if the user accept the battle it will turn into 1. The user has to keep refreshing the page to keep doing the select. So if the user aceppts the battle the vale becomes 1 but the user has to refresh the page to do the select again.

So i need a way of doing the select in jquery so when livebattle turns into 1 when the user accepts the battle it will redirect the user to the battle with out refreshing the page.

Comment: Please try to educate yourself about javascript (client side) and server side code and the differences. Your post reads like you have no idea that sql needs to be executed in a server side environment (the actual webserver) and that javascript runs on the client side where sql is not present.

Comment: I think you are mistaken the word jQuery in this context. Do you need a query for your sql database or do you need javascript jQuery code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for AJAX, the jQuery manual has [a section on it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using jquery ajax.

Combine ajax and setTimeout to refresh your ajax function looking for live battle, if you got one battle you load the battle and you stop looking for new battle (if the result of your ajax function is 1 you load the battle and stop call setTimeout, else you use setTimeout again), then when the battle end you call again the ajax function through setTimeout.